# C++ - Too Many Initializers for Arrays

Tags: c++, c, multidimensional-array, initialization

I have made an array like this but then it keeps saying I had too many initializers. How can I fix this error?

```
        int people[6][9] = {{0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0}};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
int people[6][9] =
{
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
};
```

Arrays in C are in the order rows then columns, so there are 6 rows of 9 integers, not 9 rows of 6 integers in the initializer for the array you defined.

Answer (score 10):

The issue here is that you have the rows/columns indices swapped in the array declaration part, and thus the compiler is confused.

Normally when declaring a multi-dimensional array, first index is for rows, second is for columns.

This form should fix it:

```
   int people[9][6] = {{0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0}};
```

Comment: @David, The indices are swapped.

Comment: Ah you were faster than me. +1

Comment: wow, thank you, that was simple enough but I haven't noticed it -_-

Answer (score 3):

You mixed the 6 and the 9 in the indexes.