# Too many initializers for char process[2][2][22]

Tags: c++

it is source code program c++, I am getting error of "too many initializers for char process[2][2][22]", how can i get rid of this error

```
int main(){
char process[2][2][22]={
"BE 4321 AU","Avanza","BE 2345 JU","Avanza",
"BE 1453 GU","Xenia","BE 2233 FI","Gran Max",
"BE 7809 GM","Mobilio","BE 4426 BI","Ertiga"
"BE 9012 AG","Pajero","BE 9320 YU","Fortuner"};
char broken[2][2][20]={"BE 4321 AU","Avanza","BE 2345 JU","Fortuner"};
int p;
system("clear");
cout<<"Please choose list vehicle\n1. Broken Vehicle\n2. Under Repair...";
cin>>p;
if(p==1){
system("clear");
cout<<"Broken Vehicle List\n\n";
cout<<"   ID Car\tMerk Car"<<endl;
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i += 1) {  
    cout<<i+1<<". ";
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j += 1) {  
    cout<<process[i][j]<<"\t";  
    }  
    cout<<endl;
}
}
else if(p==2){
system("clear");
cout<<"Under Repair Vehicle List\n\n";
cout<<"   ID Car\tCar Merk"<<endl;
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i += 1) {  
    cout<<i+1<<". ";
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j += 1) {  
    cout<<broken[i][j]<<"\t";  
    }  
    cout<<endl;
}  
}
else{
cout<<"Wrong Choose";
}
}
```

What's my problem? I checked other forums and this one for answers but found nothing that helped.

Comment: Answer can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335747/c-too-many-initializers-for-arrays)

Comment: How would you divide sixteen strings into two groups containing two strings each?